# How to redirect users without permission to view content to a custom page?

Tags: redirect, permissions

I want users who don't have permission to view content to be redirected to a page when they are presented with the default "Nothing Found" page. I've already redirected 404s but this is not exactly a 404. The content exists, they just don't have permission to view it.

Answer (score 0):

Redirects and forced 404 are not that good for SEO, also might hurt user experience.

I recommend that you take this approach (if you're code savvy):

```
<?php
//Your page template

//Check if user have permission
if ( $permission ) {

     //All your page/post content here
}

//Else user have no permission -> show him something else like notice
else {

    ?>
    <h1>You don't have permission to see that page.</h1>
    <a href="//www.site.com/buy-access/">Press here to buy access!</a>

    <?php

    //Or whatever your page / bussiness model is
} ?>
```

Let me know if that's approach works for you.

Comment: I found something at the theme level that let me customise the presentation when a user tries to view content for which they have no permissions. Thanks though. Your post got me looking for a similar conditional already in the code. 

I'm not so worried about SEO. This is a site for my students only. Anyone else who visits is arbitrary.

Comment: Im glad if that helped you in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You should hook into `template_redirect`. Add the following into your functions.php.

`template_redirect` is the last hook that is loaded before any HTML content is output. Once HTML is output, `wp_redirect` will generate errors.

You did not mention how you were verifying permissions for the users but I presume you have this in hand.

```
function redirect_users()    {
    if( is_admin() )
        return;

    if( !$permission )    {
        wp_redirect( 'http://pagetoredirectto.com' );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_users' );
```

[Codex: wp_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)

[Codex: template_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect)

Comment: I wonder where I could view a concise list of WP hooks. Those seem handy.